# Sharepoint people picker with PropertyFieldPeoplePicker (typescript)

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, peoplepicker

i recently stumbled a sharepoint problem which should be simple, i just cant get it to work :(.

In the code here i have a simple searchbox nothing special about it

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SearchBox } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/SearchBox';

export class Searchbox extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <SearchBox/>
        );
    }
}
```

Under the searchbox i would like to add a people picker (**no relation to the searchbox**) according to https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldPeoplePicker/

which esssentially means: adding these few lines of cones

```
import { PropertyFieldPeoplePicker, PrincipalType } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldPeoplePicker';

import { IPropertyFieldGroupOrPerson } from "@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldPeoplePicker";

export interface IPropertyControlsTestWebPartProps {
    people: IPropertyFieldGroupOrPerson[];
}
```

According the above link, i have to use  this, to use the people picker.

```
PropertyFieldPeoplePicker('people', {
    label: 'PropertyFieldPeoplePicker',
    initialData: this.properties.people,
    allowDuplicate: false,
    principalType: [PrincipalType.Users, PrincipalType.SharePoint, 
PrincipalType.Security],
    onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
    context: this.context,
    properties: this.properties,
    onGetErrorMessage: null,
    deferredValidationTime: 0,
    key: 'peopleFieldId'
})
```

but whatever i do, i just am not able to add the people picker underneath my searchbox

can anybody tell me how it is done?
thankyou very much in advance!

I have done the getting started part, but i just am not able to get the people picker tab to show up, i cant even get it to compile :/

Comment: Do you use sharepoint framework?

Comment: in this example yes, i am using it :)